# Issue with SP2013 Central Admin

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Ok so I was trying to run SharePoint 2013 Config wizard to upgrade my site and it seems that it has failed and now my sites are find but the CA doesn't open.

When I run `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures`

It gets to task 6 and fails with this error:

> Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Webs'.

So then I thought I could just reprovision my CA so I ran this.
`psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -unprovision`

It also errors out with the same error.

What is this Webs?  Is there a way around this?  Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps: http://sharepointjotter.blogspot.in/2012/08/sharepoint-2010-exception-invalid.html

Comment: did you know the name of the content db which is throwing the error? how many content DB u have?

Comment: I ran the command: 
Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://sp2013:23191 | Get-SPContentDatabase | Select ID,Name, Webapplication | Format-list  To get the correct content DB for Centrla admin page.  The i ran this command: Test-SPcontentdatabase -Identity SharePoint_AdminContent_b5141d15-7b49-440c-bf3f-cbb621fdbf96 it came back wiht the same error invlaid object 'Webs'

Answer (score 1):

Un-mount the content databases and re-run your upgrade so it completes. When it's done, attach each content database one by one and let them upgrade.

After they are finished check access to CA (if you have removed CA, then you will need to re-provision at this point).

Comment: it errors out the same way.  I think the error is in the Sharepoint_config DB.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of customization you may want to just setup a new farm and attach your content DB's.  You can do it on the same server - you'll just need to clean up the service DB's, and old farm DB's after the fact.  B/C SharePoint updates can't be rolled back I always suggest having good server and DB backups prior to updates.  If you have the patience a MS support call might be worth it.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking.  The SharePoint server itself is a VM and I can restore pretty fast.  Now the SQl DB that it is attached it it possible ot just restore the server then attach it to the DB?  Thanks.